# I can't connect to a MongoDb Docker container from VS Code

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker

I am working on a Rest API and trying to connect to a MongoDb Docker container. I am on a Windows 10 machine and managed to get Docker up and running using Bash and Oracle Virtualbox VM. I ran $ docker run --rm --name mongo -d -p 27017:27017 -v mongodbdata:/data/db mongo:4.0.4 in Bash.
 I ran docker inspect and the ports are exposed as follows:

```
"NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "27017/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "27017
```

In network settings I have

```
NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "f7d140fc6f524c8e854ced371c19ff4661f899bc96a42f7e817b301a9a514887",  
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "27017/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "27017"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/f7d140fc6f52",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "fafa4bd9c05743874fa6783fce5b40c74cea0032cf51f35182efdc5eafd3156e", 
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"
```

I am using c# Visual Studio Code and try to connect to the MongoDb Extension with the connection mongodb://locahost:27017 but I am getting ERRCONN REFUSED. I have tried using all combos of Mongodb:// localhost, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.2 and 0.0.0.0 but no luck. Also when I run the API I am getting "port 27017" actively refused the connection".
 I am concerned there is some sort of conflict between Windows10, Bash, VS Code and Docker and they can't talk to each other.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using exactly the same as docker.  The extra setting may be causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through some of the other answers here, I found out if you run "docker-machine ls" you get the IP of the VM running docker and that's the IP you need to use if using VirtualBox. Connected to Mongo straight away.
Cheers!